# Can I split a Yii controller into multiple files?

Tags: php, yii, directory-structure

I have a controller that is starting to feel very bloated.  Some of the actions themselves are very large and much as I try to split things up, navigating this file is getting tiresome.

I was wondering if there is any way, and specifically any convention, for managing very large controllers? Is there a way to split a controller up into easier-to-manage sections?

I see that there is a CAction class. Is this the way to go?  What about methods that aren't actions?

Comment: I'm here to learn about how I can avoid doing that. Obviously I understand that it's a problem, or I wouldn't be asking the question.

I feel like CAction (placing actions in separate files) might be an appropriate course of action, but I'm hoping people might have insight into why this problem tends to arise in the first place and into when this course of action is appropriate or not.

Thank you for a completely unconstructive comment.

Comment: Also, although you removed the mvc tag, I would argue that this is relevant, because even though I'm asking for framework-specific advice, I think it would be useful for myself (and any others) to learn how one might divide a controller into multiple files and why it may or may not be appropriate. (including why the problem shouldn't arise and what might lead it to arise)

Comment: Your question boils down to: "my class is too long, what to do?". The reason why classes are too long is because they violate some of SOLID principles (most likely - [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)). And if "controller" has too many responsibilities, then it is not a controller (because in MVC controllers are responsible for altering state of model layer and view ... that's it). Thus the question has nothing to do with MVC.

Comment: I'm now reading up on SOLID and SRP, so thanks. I feel like my controller isn't actually doing a whole lot.  There are only six actions, it's just that two of them run through a few switch statements to check what has actually been submitted to create the appropriate models.  Maybe I'll write a different question specifically pertaining to managing multiple models at once. That last comment of yours was actually helpful, so thanks for that :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read this link http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.best-practices to improve your structure with `MVC`. 
Besides, If you want to make your controller be simple then you can use CAction. 
From http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CAction:

> CAction provides a way to divide a complex controller into smaller actions in separate class files.

To make your model be lean, you can use `Behaviors` from Yii.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your controller is bloated because it's doing things that should be sent to the model? Controllers should act as traffic cops. They respond to a request, gather the needed data (from various models), and then send that data to a view. Maybe your controller is doing some of the work that your model(s) should be doing?

Comment: That's mainly what this controller is doing.  I'm starting to think I should have organized something differently... The heavy parts of the controller are just processing a lot of user input to save a model which can have one of 4 related models saved with it.  To be honest, the related model is also large.

Comment: I think the bloat is coming from the fact that the related models are also being saved in this controller.  Is there a way to split that up?

Comment: Emm ... @Gary. What an interesting definition of "controller" you have. Could you please add some references, because I pretty sure that it is **completely wrong**.

Comment: @tereško I'd be interested to see what your definition is, as I can't imagine the controller being considered any other way. A few references:


Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Quote: "A controller can send commands to the model to update the model's state (e.g., editing a document). It can also send commands to its associated view to change the view's presentation of the model (e.g., by scrolling through a document)."

Comment: Another link: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ModelViewController

Quote: "An easy way to understand MVC: the model is the data, the view is the window on the screen, and the controller is the glue between the two.... The controller mediates communication and unifies validation"

Comment: @Gary where does it say that "(controllers) respond to a request" or "(controllers) gather the needed data and then send that data to a view."?

Comment: @tereško This is intrinsic to the MVC framework itself. The user enters a URL (or one is provided in an ajax call) and that url is routed to a controller (although some frameworks use Routes for simpler needs). The controller then calls the appropriate models for the data needed, and then sends that data to the correct view. What, in your opinion, does this work instead?

Comment: First, there's no need to be rude or condescending. If you can't discuss things in a mature fashion, you shouldn't be here. Second, not all frameworks implement MVC, but some (many, actually) certainly do. Yii, Codeigniter, Symfony -- all are MVC-based frameworks. Third, I never said that the Model was a class or object. But the Model does consist of classes and objects.

Comment: Fourth, I never said Routing was a de facto part of MVC. I said that some frameworks, such as Laravel, provide a Routing class on top of its Controllers for cases when a full Controller is overkill to handle a simple page call. I don't claim to be an expert on anything, but my views on MVC (no pun intended) are completely accurate. I have no wish to discuss this further because this is well off-topic, and you seem to have no interest in mature conversation.